# How can i get DOM of specific page like "google.com"?

Tags: javascript, web, dom, get, fetch

for this problem I need to say I use fetch method but some web, like [google](https://google.com) and ..
**does not** allow it.

I want to get DOM of a page for tracking it, for example : I wanna check if an element change let me know.
How can I get an specific web page DOM without exception, like: google in using fetch method?

If you have another solutions, may you tell me (With Java script)?

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you've tried so far.

Comment: What is your approach ? Please try by yourself and share your code and then ask for corrections, it will help you to grow more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; You don't

You can insert a page via `<iframe>`, but it won't (for security reasons) let you access any of its data, thus nor the DOM.

You can't fetch the HTML of `google.com` either, it is because Google doesn't want to give you the HTML... You can, however, create a proxy server, because a nodeJS server **can** fetches the HTML of google.com. But then it will be simple HTML yet to be parsed...

Comment: Hello again. You sure about that ??? In your opinion there are no solutions to get all web's DOM without nodejs??

Comment: In your opinion there are no solutions to get DOM of web without Nodejs ??

Comment: Indeed, and even with nodeJS you won’t tiger doom but rather the HTML that you may parse to DOM

Comment: Imagine if I could create a page with google code but I could see every part of the page... for example the password input, that would be quite a problem, don’t you think?